# Kendoui MVC EditorTemplateName do not work in PopUp edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I want to use EditorTemplateName for foreign key Column in KendoUi grid.

when Grid Edit Mode is InLine all thing is OK and My Template Loaded. but when change mode to Popup not load template. 
how can fix it?

```js
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductId).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Title);

        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryySelectList, "Value", "Text"))
                   .EditorTemplateName("MyTemplate");

        columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
    })
    .Editable(edit => edit
        .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(15)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ProductId);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("FillGrid", "Products"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Products"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Products"))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rendering is indeed not handled the same when using `InLine`/`InCell` vs. `Popup`. For the latter, the editor template that is actually going to be used is inferred from the name, so you'd put a `Product.cshtml` template in `~Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`.

This article covers this in detail:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates.