# How to bind a Kendo UI Grid to a collection of my model in an editor template using MVC Razor

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I Have a Grid that is based on a Model Similar to

```
public class UserModel
{
  ...
  public IList<UserOrgModel> UserOrg {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

This Grid is set to `.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("...")` and open this editorTemplate to edit the row I selected (by pressing Action Button).

This Editor Template contain also a Grid that would be bind to my collection.

I defined my grid this way

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UserOrg)
  .Name("blabla")
  .Columns(col => 
  {
    col.Bound(c => c.Id);
  })
)
```

When I do this my grid based on my collection is always empty.
Any Idea how I can use Kendo UI  and its grid to do what I want.  I don't know how to bind my grid with the "collection" of my model.

Comment: Are you trying to use a grid within a grid? And you want the "inside" grid to be bound to a collection?

Comment: With Kendo you can Update a Row with a property set to .Mode(GridEditMode.Popup)...  This Popup Open up a defined EditorTemplate.  In this Template a want another Grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my Answer here:
[Grid Popup Editing Navigation Property Collection with nested Grid](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/grid-popup-editing-navigation-property-collection-with-nested-grid)

I Downloaded the demo and All I wanted was there. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I didn't fully understand your question. But if you are trying to bind the grid to a collection in your model. Here you go:

In the Kendo UI online demos, [this example may help you](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/local-data.html). Scroll to the bottom portion of the page, click on "ASP.NET MVC" then click the "local_data.cshtml". Here is the code example edited to be more like your example:

```
@model UserModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UserOrg)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        //set up your columns here
        columns.Bound(u => u.Name).Title("Name");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(430)) 
    .Filterable()    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)        
     )
)
```

**Update**

I found another SO article that may help you: [Kendoui MVC EditorTemplateName do not work in PopUp edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677837/kendoui-mvc-editortemplatename-do-not-work-in-popup-edit-mode)

I think what you want is to create an editor template in the `~\View\Shared\EditorTemplates` folder that you reference using the `column.EditorTemplateName("..")`.

Comment: I edited my question... maybe you'll understand better